# SUSY condition on string theory

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, branes

In each string theory, there is some condition so called [SUSY condition](http://www.google.cz/search?as_q=string+theory&as_epq=susy+condition).

**I want to know susy condition for 
Type I, Type II, and Heterotic string.**

Can anyone give some brief explanation about this?
And I want to know why this condition is necessary.

Comment: Relevant text - Polchinski Vol. 2

Comment: @Prahar, Thanks, Can you give me the relevant chapters?

Comment: Hi phy_math: Resource recom questions are restricted on Phys.SE (and likely essentially a duplicate of similar resource recom questions in ST), so I removed that part. Moreover, it is implicitly implied that _any_ Phys.SE question is indirectly asking for resource recom.

Comment: , @Qmechanic, Thanks!, I will be aware of this from now.